# Changing position of dynamically created column in GridView - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I am having trouble adding new columns to `GridView` control from code-behind.
I use `DataTable` as a datasource for my `GridView` control, and, after binding it, every column that I add to GridView appears at the left side of the control. I need to change it's position.

Please note, that I need to add columns from the code-behind, not from the `.aspx` file.

My `GridView` definition in `.aspx` file:

```
<asp:GridView ID="devicesTable" runat="server" OnRowEditing="deviceEdit">
</asp:GridView>
```

And the piece of code, where I try to add a column:

```
StoredProcedure connection = new StoredProcedure("usp_nsi_mpd_sel");

DataTable dataTable = connection.ExecReader();
ButtonField buttonField = new ButtonField();
buttonField.CommandName = "Select";
buttonField.ButtonType = ButtonType.Button;
buttonField.Text = "Edit";

devicesTable.DataSource = dataTable;
devicesTable.Columns.Add(buttonField);
devicesTable.DataBind();
```

And this results in `buttonField` appearing at the left side of the `GridView`. How do I change it's position?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the main issue is dynamically changing the order of columns you can see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28611217/215752

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to change the position of any column in the GridView i had to bound fields to my data source.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.Use `insert` for dynamically created columns

```
devicesTable.Columns.Insert(0, buttonField)
```

[DataGridViewColumnCollection.Insert Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumncollection.insert%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your reply, but this method says that even 0 index is out of range. i found the solution already, but it involves a bit of asp code :)

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="devicesTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="deviceEdit">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="mpd_num" HeaderText="Номер платы"/>
<asp:BoundField DataField="mpd_imei" HeaderText="IMEI" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="mpd_sim_num" HeaderText="Номер SIM-карты" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="rev1" HeaderText="ТИЖМ.687252.002.01 ТЗ" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="rev2" HeaderText="ТИЖМ.687252.002.02 ТЗ" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="rev3" HeaderText="ТИЖМ.687252.002.03 ТЗ" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

Comment: oh, and the main thing :D


<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" Text="Редактировать" />

Comment: and after that i could get to my fields by indexes. seems like the only solution for now. unfortunately, i don't have time now to think of a better way to fulfil my idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a thing like that,

```
   private void AdjustColumnOrder()
{
    customersDataGridView.Columns["CustomerID"].Visible = false;
    customersDataGridView.Columns["ContactName"].DisplayIndex = 0;
    customersDataGridView.Columns["ContactTitle"].DisplayIndex = 1;
    customersDataGridView.Columns["City"].DisplayIndex = 2;
    customersDataGridView.Columns["Country"].DisplayIndex = 3;
    customersDataGridView.Columns["CompanyName"].DisplayIndex = 4;

}
```

Comment: i can't acces columns by name because i haven't specified them in .aspx page. i found the solution myself, thanks :)